# How to implement payment gateway/plugin based on total amount in woo commerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I want to implement a payment plugin for woo commerce website when the amount exceeds a particular limit.

Use case: My client wants to show only the Cash On Delivery(COD) payment option if the amount is below of Rs.100 but if the amount exceeds Rs.100, then show COD as well as other payment method option too. Is there any plugin for this purpose on WordPress?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

WooCommerce **[Conditional Shipping and Payments](https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-shipping-and-payments/)** premium plugin providing this type of features. Would you please check below links?

> [**Conditional Shipping and Payments**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-conditional-shipping-and-payments/)

This extension **will not create any new payment gateways for you**. However, it allows you to **conditionally activate existing payment gateways** based on conditions such as the selected shipping method, selected billing/shipping country and state, cart/order total, user role, user e-mail, and more.